# using the popover plugin for Twitter bootstrap is is possible to set a custom div as the hover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that i want to be my 'popover' is it possible to use twitter bootstrap's popover plugin to handle this?

I have found a number of options on the documentation page but nothing that mentions custom html http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

Comment: Are you looking for someting like this? http://jsfiddle.net/shhXD/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `content()` option if html is set to true.

```
$("#myElement").popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  content: function() {
    // create your element here
    return 'hello <strong>world</strong>';
  }
});
```

The only thing is once you leave the hovered element the popover will disappear. So if your popover has links or elements that can be interacted with you'll need to set trigger = 'manual' as an option and handle when to show and hide the popover yourself - although I'm sure plugins exist already for this type of behaviour.

Otherwise the popover will disappear when your mouse leaves the element that caused the trigger.